# Online editor for word documents

Tags: ms-word, editor, wysiwyg

Can anyone recommend a really good online wysiwyg editor? I'm looking for the following features:

- saving of document in a Word-compatible format (.doc, .docx, .rtf)
- accurate cut/paste from Word
- support of most Word features, including paragraph numbering
- customizable. I need to add my own special handling for changes

Because the app will be used in a company intranet, it's not vital that it runs in all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

have you tried office live or google docs?

**[OfficeLive](http://www.officelive.com/en-us)**

**[googledocs](http://docs.google.com)**

Comment: Adding to the above post, you may also want to check out Zoho Writer (http://writer.zoho.com/ and http://writer.zoho.com/editor.im )

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
I'm not aware that I can incorporate google docs or office live into an app and customize them - though I'd be delighted if you can correct me on this.

Zoho looks much more promising - but the current version unfortunately does not handle paragraph numbering correctly and is therefore a nogo.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Inetword](http://www.inetword.com/)

I found it is best for online Document editing, and does almost all functionality done by MS office.

Comment: Unfortunately, according to their website, iNetWord services is terminating as of March 1st, 2012.

Answer (score 0):

You might wish to consider Native Documents (a commercial solution, new in 2018): https://www.nativedocuments.com which we have designed to be easy to embed. (Disclosure: I have an interest here)

> saving of document in a Word-compatible format (.doc, .docx, .rtf)

Supports loading of doc and docx. (Not RTF yet). Save/export to docx or pdf.

> support of most Word features, including paragraph numbering

High fidelity layout/rendering of Word documents is a key feature.  Its good enough to be used for PDF Conversion.

> customizable. I need to add my own special handling for changes

The web client is written in ReactJS, which you can customize.